# How to check image height and width before upload in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactjs and right now i am trying to validate image height and width before upload,how can i do this ? i want user cant upload more than 200*200 (pixel)/dynamic,How can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
const createOfficer = async () => {
   setShowSpinner(true)
    const formData = createFormDataObject(newOfficerData)
    const res = await putAPIFormDataWrapper(editDepartmentUrl, formData)
    if (!res.isError) {
      setShowSpinner(false)
      props.notify(res.data.data.message, 'success')
    } else {
      setShowSpinner(false)
      props.notify(res.error.message, 'error')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the dimensions of an image you can use the `Image` object. Here's an example:

```
const checkDimensions = (imgUrl) => {
     const img = new Image();
     img.src = imgUrl;
     img.onload = () => {
         const width = img.naturalWidth;
         const height = img.naturalHeight;
         if (width > 200 || height > 200) {
            // Image dimensions are larger than the maximum allowed
            // You can either return false to prevent the image from being uploaded
            // or display an error message to the user
            return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `URL.createObjectURL` method to pass an image blob instead of a URL strng.

Comment: Vina can you please update in my code so i can check and impliment at my side